# pass value to route and then controller

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

this is my view

```
<a href="{{URL::route('audit_crawling')}}"class="clear active"> </a>
```

and i want to pass value to route, value is in $id variable

```
  {{URL::route('audit_crawling'.$id)}}
```

and i want to get this value here and pass to controller

```
Route::get('/dashboard',[
    'as'=>'audit_crawling',
    'uses'=>'ProjectController@audit_crawling'
]);
```

and this is my controller code

```
 function audit_crawling($id)
     {
     data=['id'=>$id];
    return view('user.project.dashboard',$data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass data to controller use:

Route:

```
Route::get('/dashboard/{id}',[
    'as'=>'audit_crawling',
    'uses'=>'ProjectController@audit_crawling'
]);
```

Controller

```
    public function audit_crawling($id) {
    echo $id;
}
```

Link :

```
<a href="{{route('audit_crawling',$id)}}" class="clear active"> </a>
```

or

`<a href="{{url('dashboard/'.$id)}}" class="clear active"> </a>`

Comment: dashboard?1 em getting id in this form.can i get url like dashboard/1

Comment: you mean `<a href="{{url('dashboard/'.$id)}}" class="clear active"> </a>`

Comment: have you modified the htaccess  file?

Comment: how about `<a href="{{url('dashboard')}}/{{$id}}" class="clear active"> </a>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105640/discussion-between-madalin-ivascu-and-umair-zahid).